# Can't show the output in html

Tags: php

I have a function wich prints a number of credits:

```
<?php
function selectCredits()
{
 include 'sqlvars.php';
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","bbbb","bbbb");
     if (!$con){
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("bbbb", $con);
  $result = mysql_query($selectCredits);

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo $row['credits'];
  }
}
?>
```

When I'm calling it from a php file by using:

```
<?php 
include 'sql.php';
selectCredits();
?>
```

I can see the output, but when I'm inside of a HTML document I can't get the result using this code:

```
 <center><b>Your credits: </b></center> <?php include 'sql.php'; selectCredits(); ?>
```

The output is always: `Your credits:` without the query result.

For sure I'm missing somthing really small. I'm not a php guy, but I'm willing to learn it, already lost an hour without any success.

Comment: That's by design: the web server won't send HTML files through the PHP interpreter. You either want to give all your HTML files the .PHP extension, or make the web server parse HTML files, or use URL rewriting for nice URLs

Comment: I just tried to parse it by adding this line `AddHandler cgi-script .html .htm` to `.htaccess` , but I got `403 Forbidden` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want html files to execute php code, try to add this line to htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Comment: Bad solution. If you have the ability to upload files, you can upload .html file and execute it.

Comment: It's the solution he was looking for. Granted, it's not a good idea to do that, but it can be done. Also, you can block the upload of .html files as you do (or should be doing) for .php files, control the chmod of the files uploaded by the users an so on...

Answer (score 1):

check your query statement '$selectCredits'. check table name and attribute name-'credits'.  The $row['credits'] is not getting its value.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your code. You have written

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo $row['credits'];
}
```

You have used mysql_fetch_array and you have echoed $row with attribute value directly. If you are using mysql_fetch_array, then use $row[0], $row[1] or $row[2] etc. All the attributes come as an array. Thats why you should treat it as array index value. So, if "credit" attribute is at the 5th column in your database, then you should echo it as

```
echo $row['4'];
```

If you use mysql_fetch_assoc() instead of mysql_fetch_array, then you can write the attribute name directly.

E.g. then you can write

```
echo $row['credits'];
```

I hope, this will solve the issue. Please ask me if you have any further questions.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array ` retrieves both associative and numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a JavaScript tag to implement the PHP file like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="credits.php"></script>`

`credits.php` would have to output:

`echo "document.write('" . $row['credits'] . "');";`

Simple :)